# Change link attributes within a class using jquery

Tags: jquery

Without manually assigning an ID to each href, the goal would be to change the URLs for both hrefs to a different URL

```
<div class="example">
        <p><a href="http://www.google.com/example?test1332">Test Site</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://www.google.com/example?test1332">Test Site</a></p>
</div>
```

This is my jquery attempt which is not working

```
$(".example").each(function() {
    this.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("href").replace("http://www.test.com"));
});
```

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n322j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want

```
$('.example a').attr('href', "http://www.test.com");
```

If you'd want to only replace part of the URL, that is keep everything apart `http://www.google.com`, then you could do

```
$(".example a").attr('href', function(i, href) {
   return href.replace("http://www.google.com", "http://www.test.com");
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DjHAp/)

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing this.

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function (){
$("div p a").attr('href',"http://www.google.com");
});
</script>
```

it also works fine.